# the largest element of a matrix product

Tags: optimization, time-complexity, linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-product

Given two matrices, I'm interested in finding the largest element of their product. I wonder if it's possible to do it significantly faster than the matrix multiplication the solution seems to require?

Comment: Do you want the exact answer ?

Comment: @SureshVenkat Yes, although I'm curious about any fast approximate solutions as well.

Comment: This might help you. `Diamond Sampling for Approximate
Maximum All-pairs Dot-product (MAD)` at https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.03872.pdf, and some [applications](http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~srelton/files/ral_seminar_May16.pdf)